# Как мне вывести картинки из админки?

Tags: python, django

Не пойму как вывести правильно картинки.

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="home"),
    path('gallery', views.gallery, name="gallery"),
    path('service', views.service, name="service"),
]
```

**settings**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**models**

```
class Images(models.Model):
    model_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'картинка'
        verbose_name_plural = 'картинки'
```

**views**

```
def gallery(request):
    num_img = Images.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/gallery.html', context={'num_img': num_img})
```

**gallery.html**

```
{% for i in num_img %}
    <img src="{{ i.model_img.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Сейчас когда я загружаю картинки то выглядит это так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В папке проекта urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
              ]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

html

```
 {% for i in num_img %}
       <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ i.model_img.url }}">
 {% endfor %}
```